# getting [ERROR] IndexError: list index out of range in lambda while trying to fetch InstanceId from RunInstance cloudtrail json log

Tags: python, json, lambda, amazon-cloudtrail

getting [ERROR] IndexError: list index out of range in lambda while trying to fetch InstanceId from RunInstance cloudtrail json log:

```
[ERROR] IndexError: list index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

any idea that how would I fetch the instaceid, and the tag from lambda_handler without any error ? any inputs

Comment: If there are no `items`, you use an empty list as the default for `.get('items')`. Trying to access the `[0]` element of an empty list will cause this error.

Comment: You need to check whether the `items` list is empty before trying to get the `instanceId`.

Comment: Sir - would you plz share the snippet for this runinstance lambda so that I can take a look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are any items before trying to access the first one. If no items are found, raise an exception.

```
def getId(event):
    items = event.get('responseElements', {}).get('instancesSet', {}).get('items')
    if items:
        return items[0]['instanceId']
    raise ValueError('No items found')
```